# Why doesn't json_decode work with this particular json object?

Tags: php, json

So I have my php script to receive a json object from http://www.reddit.com/search.json via a http GET request and through previous testing, DOES successfully get a json object. However, when I use json_decode on this object, I get an error:

> Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home/hudson/ug/xbvg52/public_html/stupid.php on line 5

Here is my (very simple) code:

```
$query = $_GET["radio"];
$url = "https://www.reddit.com/search.json?q=".$query;
$response = file_get_contents($url);
echo json_decode($response);
```

How can I convert this JSON object into a string?

Comment: What value does $query have?

Comment: the response you get _is_ a string, json_decode converts that into an (array of) object(s)

Comment: @Quentin $query has whatever was entered into the html form on the previous page

Comment: @HJGBAUM — Obviously, but unless you give us an example it is hard to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `print_r (json_decode($response));` the result of [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is an object so `echo` wont work

Answer (score 3):

You can't echo `json_decode` because this function makes an array of objects, or a simple object. Try running `var_dump(json_decode($response));` and see for yourself.

You're getting this error because `echo` expects a string and you're sending an object.

You could transform this array into a string in order to echo it.

Comment: Don't need to transform the array, he just needs to not transform the json string (which he wants) into an array/object in the first place

Comment: Well that's a solution. But if he wants specific values then he need to specify it in the echo.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error you are seeing is because you are echoing an object. Echo is only used for strings. Use print_r or var_dump instead.